# How can I call the same functions in onCreate() and onResume() methods?

Tags: java, android, activity-lifecycle

I want to run the same functions in `onCreate()` and `onResume()`. The functions basically record in 10 seconds and then stop and play the recorded sound.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    new CountDownTimer(
            10000, // 10 second countdown
            9999) { // onTick time, not used

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // Not used
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            isRecording = false;
        }
    }.start();

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            isRecording = true;
            record(); // starts to record
        }
    });
    thread.start(); // thread start
    // thread to start

    play();
}
```

If I hit the <kbd>Home</kbd> button, then the app got put into the background. Now if I hit the app's icon button again, I'd like to call the same recording and playing functions.

Can I do same thing like this in `onResume()`? Basically duplicate the same thing.

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    new CountDownTimer(
            10000, // 10 second countdown
            9999) { // onTick time, not used 

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // Not used
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            isRecording = false;
        }
    }.start();

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            isRecording = true;
            record(); // starts to record
        }
    });
    thread.start(); // thread start

    play();
}
```

Comment: Create your own method?

Comment: No need to do it in onCreate, just put the code in onResume.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the stuff you want to run in onResume().  onResume() will get called after onCreate() the first time then it will get called each time the application comes out of the background.

Activity lifecycle can be found (visually) here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

[image]